# How to stop the UIKeyboard return key from working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a UITextField thats currently in a UITableViewCell, when you select the UITextField the UIkeyboard automatically comes up.

I would like to know how I can just ignore the return key when its pressed.. there is a feature I have no implemented yet to skip UITextFields its causing me some errors and before I preview my app I would like to disable it to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you'll need to use [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html), specifically, `textFieldShouldReturn:`. All you have to do is specify that your class will conform to this protocol in your interface, and specify that this class as the delegate on the textfield's delegate property and you're good to go. That is, after returning no from `textFieldShouldReturn:`. Or of course, this can be done conditionally.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (someCondition == YES) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: oh yep perfect that worked.. i was going down a completely different route.. turns out I already had that method created and was returning YES so the other stuff I was trying was getting overridden..

Comment: @HurkNburkS Glad to hear it helped!